# Javascript: split string with special superscript symbols

Tags: javascript, string, substring, superscript

How to split `$str` string into two parts where the second part of the string starts with any of symbols such as `²,³,.., ⁿ, º,ʳ,ᵈ,™,℠,®` (something small on top excluding  `', ", *,^` - there are many I guess, including all latin letters but "superscripted" probably).

The first substring (may be empty) + the second substring (may be empty) == original string.

I guess the keyword for that is **superscript**. A superscript is a number, figure, symbol, or indicator that is smaller than the normal line of type and is set slightly above the baseline.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use positive look ahead with the symbols.

```js
var string = 'abc²xyz',
    result = string.split(/(?=[²³ⁿºʳᵈ™℠®])/);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: ⁰ ¹ ² ³ ⁴ ⁵ ⁶ ⁷ ⁸ ⁹ ⁺ ⁻ ⁼ ⁽ ⁾ ₀ ₁ ₂ ₃ ₄ ₅ ₆ ₇ ₈ ₉ ₊ ₋ ₌ ₍ ₎  ᵃ ᵇ ᶜ ᵈ ᵉ ᶠ ᵍ ʰ ⁱ ʲ ᵏ ˡ ᵐ ⁿ ᵒ ᵖ ʳ ˢ ᵗ ᵘ ᵛ ʷ ˣ ʸ ᶻ ᴬ ᴮ ᴰ ᴱ ᴳ ᴴ ᴵ ᴶ ᴷ ᴸ ᴹ ᴺ ᴼ ᴾ ᴿ ᵀ ᵁ ⱽ ᵂ ₐ ₑ ₕ ᵢ ⱼ ₖ ₗ ₘ ₙ ₒ ₚ ᵣ ₛ ₜ ᵤ ᵥ ₓ ᵅ ᵝ ᵞ ᵟ ᵋ ᶿ ᶥ ᶲ ᵠ ᵡ ᵦ ᵧ ᵨ ᵩ ᵪ

Comment: @NinaScholz That the OP asked for **all** superscripted symbols, not just the ones from his example ("*such as …*")

Comment: @Bergi, i am still aware of the question, but it is to broad, because a group of super or sup characters is m. e. not possible.

Comment: Then *that* should be the answer. Or a comment. Or a close vote.

Comment: @NinaScholz OP asked for all characters. Just a list of all these would not be enough for an answer. You wrote a reasonable answer and I did not dare to edit it (and add this list), so I just commented a more complete list of characters to check for.